# Is it dangerous to have table with big number of columns?

Tags: oracle10g

Is it a dangerous practice to have tables with large number of columns. Is there possibility of some performance or memory issues? My DB is Oracle 10g. It is easier to add columns for existing table then rearrange structure of db in my case. I'm talking about 30-50 additional columns to the table that already has had about 50 columns in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't dangerous, *per se*, but it is usually a sign of poor design. Are these extra columns mostly diverse and unique, or are you adding something like the following?

```
mon_price, tue_price, wed_price, ..., mon_qty, tue_qty, ...
```

EDIT (in response to confirmation by OP):

If it's anything like what I depict above, that's definitely a bad idea. In the case of my example, normalise the schema by creating a subtable with columns `parent_id, day_of_week, price, qty`.

Comment: mon_price, tue_price, wed_price, ..., mon_qty, tue_qty, .

Comment: Not necessarily always a bad idea. I've done this in one application. My first design, fully normalized, with separate tables as suggested, was a beast to get all the constraints right and performed very poorly. My second design, with dozens of columns in one table, was much simpler, all constraints were easily declared, and was much faster. Sure, a partially denormalized design has plenty of disadvantages but if these are accepted then it has its uses.

Comment: I hereby formally retract my previous comment! That application where I had several repeating columns *did* work, but the advantages that it gave for UI design ended up being outweighed by the complexity of the code and the difficulty of adding additional columns. I've since replaced the application with one that uses a normalized design, and both the UI, the application code and reporting are much simpler now. +1 to you Marcelo :)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: Thank you so much for having the cajones to publicly change your mind based on experience. It isn't easy to leave one's former ignorance on display (I say so without conceit; I have a few highly embarrassing instances of my own on SO), but it is a valuable contribution to the community.

Answer (score 0):

Large number of columns definitely results in reduced space requirements ( as other fields are not duplicated ).  I have a use case  where I am thinking of having 120 columns where 93=31*3 columns are used to store 3 distinct daily metrics. I would like to know if there are any specifc performance issues with this approach ( compared to having a 3 columns and a separate column as day-of-month )